# How to specify different port for clojure app

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, ring

I'm trying to learn clojure, and I'm setting up Hello World app. Whe I try to run the app with lein server command, I get the following command:

2022-03-28 20:15:50.629:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@12d1b1b: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

My question is, how can I change the default app that app is running in? I tried with killing specific process on that port, but for some reason that does not work.
This is my handler.clj file:

```
(ns todoapp.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

This is mine project.clj file:

```
(defproject todoapp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.5"]]
  :ring {:handler todoapp.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.2"]]}})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Running the server on a different port is covered in the [`lein-ring` documentation](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#readme)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the port by:

- command line option: `lein ring server port-number`
- specify `PORT`or `SSLPORT` environment var
- add `:port` key to project.clj: `{... :ring {:port 1234 ...}}`